# Objective C - Access Method befor changing View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I'm trying to call a method before I change the ViewController. Here's my Code:

ViewController.m (First View, here I want to set a String)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginCorrect"]){
       [segue.destinationViewController setMail:@"asd"];
    }
}
```

ViewControllerMainMenu.h

```
- (void)setMail:(NSString*)mail;
@property (strong) NSString *userMail;
```

ViewControllerMainMenu.m

```
- (void)setMail:(NSString*)mail
{
    self.userMail = mail;
}
```

As you can see, I want to use the userMail String in the second View, which I get in the first View (a classic Login should be the result).

But I always become this Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setMail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147635080'
```

Hope you can help me, Thanks!
Emanuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take reference of YourViewController

```
UITabBarController *tabbar=[segue destinationViewController];

// i am assuming YourViewController at index 0

YourViewController *vc=(YourViewController *)[tabbar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[vc setMail:@"asd"]
```

Answer (score 2):

YOu are calling a method on tabbarcontroller which is rely on viewcontroller, so call it properly to reach your goal

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending a message to the object that can not handle this. This is caused because you think you are sending it to the right object but in fact (in runtime) it is not. You should debug and see what is exactly the problem. It might be the retrieving the object you are sending a message or you should have some check if that sending a message should occur in fact - all that depends what you want to achieve. Maybe you will need some casting to help compiler figure out whit what to deal with

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your segue destination is a `UITabBarController` and in it you have a custom `UIViewController`? We'll need to see proper code in order to answer properly but here's my best guess for now.

First you need to import your class...

```
#import "ViewControllerMainMenu.h"
```

Then in prepareForSegue...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginCorrect"]){
       UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;

       ViewControllerMainMenu *controller = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];

       controller.mail = @"asd";
    }
}
```

Obviously, this depends on exactly how everything is set up but you should be able to adapt it from here.